# How to clear dynamically added TextInputs in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a bit of an issue resetting my TextInputs after submitting because they were added dynamically.

I currently have my js code like this

```
                    <FlatList
                      data={this.state.items}
                      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.party_id}
                      renderItem={({item}) =>
                        <View style={styles.InputBox}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.InputPartyLabel}><Text>{item.party_name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                            <TextInput
                                ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
                                style={styles.Input}
                                placeholder="Number of votes"
                                onChangeText={result => this.collateResults(item.party_name, result)}
                                placeholderTextColor="#bbb"
                                autoCapitalize='none'
                                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                              />
                        </View> } />
```

I added this `ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}` but it only clears the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You need `this.textInput` to be an array. And then push to that array when setting the refs

```js
<TextInput
                                ref={input => this.textInput.push(input)}
                                style={styles.Input}
                                placeholder="Number of votes"
                                onChangeText={result => this.collateResults(item.party_name, result)}
                                placeholderTextColor="#bbb"
                                autoCapitalize='none'
                                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                              />
```

Comment: thanks for this. took me a step further but still gives me an error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` when i use for loop to try and clear all the inputs `this.textInput[i].clear()` however, `this.textInput[0].clear()` clears one input.